# Update files inside a Docker container and update it outside the container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

I create an Ionic page inside the container using the container shell and I want to obtain the result files outside the container. I have the src/ folder in a docker volume, if I update the code it updates too in the container but not in the opposite direction. **How can I obtain the updates that I make inside the container outside of it?**

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:alpine3.16
WORKDIR /project-meals-mobile-frontend/

RUN npm install -g @ionic/cli@6.20.6
RUN npm install

COPY src/ /project-meals-mobile-frontend/src/

EXPOSE 8100
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  ionic:
    container_name: project-meals-ionic
    restart: always
    build: ./
    command:
      ionic serve -p=8100 --external
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app
      - ./node_modules/:/node_modules/
    ports:
      - "8100:8100"
```

I execute this to go into the container shell:

```
docker exec -it project-meals-ionic sh
```

Then I execute the command to generate a page:

```
ionic generate page schedule
```

It works if I do an `ls` I have the corresponding files:

```
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan  5 15:09 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan  4 21:24 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           637 Jan  5 15:09 app-routing.module.ts
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1170 Jan  4 14:28 app.component.html
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1939 Jan  4 14:28 app.component.scss
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1523 Jan  4 14:28 app.component.spec.ts
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           703 Jan  4 14:28 app.component.ts
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           578 Jan  4 14:28 app.module.ts
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan  4 19:28 folder
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan  5 15:09 schedule
```

**I need this folder outside the container to edit the code and upload it to git.**

Comment: Volumes are only present during container runtime, not image buildtime. To my knowledge, there is no way to extract data from within the container to the docker host during image build time.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do things in the wrong direction – making changes inside a running process and hoping your source tree will reflect it.  I'd make the changes in your host source tree first, run `npm test` or similar on your host outside of Docker, and then rebuild the image for an integration test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi problem was that in the `docker-compose.yml` in the volume declaration I have **to use the absolute path inside the docker container not the relative path of the `WORKDIR` of the `Dockerfile`**. For now if I create/edit a file inside the container it reflects out the container.
This is the valid `docker-compose.yml` code:

```
    volumes:
      - ./src:/project-meals-mobile-frontend/src/
      - ./node_modules/:/node_modules/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `docker cp` to copy the files from the container to your host machine.

syntax:

```
docker cp containerName:/path/to/folder /path/on/host
```

Official doc: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/